# Open sans pixelated in Firefox under Win7

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I just reinstalled Win 7 professional  64 bit version and now suddenly the open sans font is displayed pixelated in Firefox, in Chrome it looks normal.
Here is an example (left Chrome, right Firefox, I recommend to click on the Image, otherwise its hard to see that the right text is pixelated):

[image]

Here is another example of a navigation with the font properties:

```
font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;
font-size: 12px;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 700;
```

and how it is displayed in Firefox and Chrome:

[image]

It used to work on Win 7 before I reinstalled it. I include the font with

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,600,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

in the header.

What can cause this behavior?

Comment: Try to check within your console if any of the css lines are overwritten. In firefox it looks like the font-weight is not properly applied.

Comment: @FrankW If I make rightclick and press 'Inspect Element'->'Computed' it shows the correct properties **font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, Arial;** alsow font-weight value is correct. But its not just the font-weight thats looks odd, its also the fact that it is so pixelated

Comment: I understand. Just wanted to check if any css properties were commented out. The reason is that the font-weight also looks off in both browsers.

Comment: Have a look at this topic on mozilla site. Try turning on cleartype. Here's a topic on mozilla's website on cleartype: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2442059

Comment: @FrankW. Could you explain how I can change the **gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.rendering_mode** value in FF? However, I dont think it will help, because the **open sans font** is also very pixelated in IE. Only Chrome seems to render it correct. In addition, it used to work on FF before I reinstalled Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to install all Windows Updates, then everything worked fine.